# Django-python: how to pass argument from child class to parent class?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class MaleManager(models.Manager):
   def get_query_set(self):
      return super('here should be EmployeeManager', self).get_query_set().filter(sex='male')

# Need to pass class name EmployeeManager to MaleManager

class EmployeeManager(MaleManager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(EmployeeManager, self).get_query_set()
```

So what I want to do here is passing EmployeeManager to GenericManager, and now have no Idea how to do that?

Comment: Please fix the numerous spelling errors in your code - I suspect they're all _meant_ to say MaleManager

Comment: Also, this question doesn't make any sense as far as I can tell. What you're describing forces a very obvious stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for, whatever reason, what you've described actually does make sense, you might be looking for the `self.__class__` property.